# First axiom of countability and finer topologies

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,T)$ and $(X,T')$ are topological spaces, where $T\subseteq T'$, then if $(X,T)$ satisfies the first axiom of countability, not necessarily does $(X,T')$ and viceversa. However, I am not able to find examples.

Comment: In one direction you can try to use the discrete topology as $T'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to come up with examples if you allow yourself to work with non-Hausdorff topologies. For example if $(X,T')$ is a non-first countable space, then we can take $T = \{\emptyset,X\}$ and $T'' = 2^X$. Then we have $T \subset T' \subset T''$ with the first and the last topologies being first countable.

So let's try for a Hausdorff example!

Consider $X = \mathbb R^\omega$, the set of sequences of real numbers.

Let $T$ be the product topology on $X$. This is metrisable, so in particular it's first countable.

Let $T'$ be the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) on $X$. It's not too difficult to show that it's not first countable and that $T \subset T'$.

And finally consider $T'' = 2^X$, i.e. the discrete topology. It's also first countable (and also metrisable) with $T' \subset T''$.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another fairly elementary way to produce a nice example.

Let $X=\{p\}\cup(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)$, where $p$ is any point not in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. Let

$$\tau=\wp(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{p\}\cup U:p\in U\subseteq X\text{ and }(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\setminus U\text{ is finite}\big\}\;.$$

In other words, each point of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is isolated in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, and the nbhds of $p$ are the cofinite subsets of $X$ that contain $p$. Then $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is even second countable. (In fact it’s homeomorphic to $\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ with the usual topology inherited from $\Bbb R$, so it’s compact and metrizable.)

Now let $\tau'$ be the [Arens-Fort topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space) on $X$: points of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ are isolated, and $U\subseteq X$ is a nbhd of $p$ if and only if $p\in U$, and there are a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ and an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$U\supseteq\{\langle k,n\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:k\ge m\text{ and }n\ge f(k)\}\;.$$

In other words, $U$ contains all but finitely many points of all but finitely many of the sets $\{k\}\times\Bbb N$. Clearly $\tau'\supseteq\tau$.

However, $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is not first countable at $p$. To see this, suppose that $\big\langle\langle m_k,n_k\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$ is a sequence in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ converging to $p$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary we may assume that $\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is strictly increasing (why?). Define

$$f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:m\mapsto\begin{cases}
n_k+1,&\text{if }m=m_k\text{ for some }k\in\Bbb N\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let $U=\{p\}\cup\{\langle k,n\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:n\ge f(k)\}$; then $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$ disjoint from $\{\langle m_k,n_k\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\}$.

Finally, let $\tau''$ be the discrete topology on $X$; certainly $\tau''\supseteq\tau'$, and $\langle X,\tau''$ is first countable (indeed, metrizable).

Ultrafilters provide another approach, if one is familiar with them. Let $X=\Bbb N\cup\{p\}$, where $p$ is any point not in $\Bbb N$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{U\subseteq\Bbb N:\Bbb N\setminus U\text{ is finite}\}$, the cofinite filter on $\Bbb N$, and let

$$\tau=\wp(\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{p\}\cup U:U\in\mathscr{F}\big\}\;;$$

then $\tau$ is a first countable topology on $X$. (In fact $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is homeomorphic to $\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ with the usual topology inherited from $\Bbb R$.)

Now let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, and let

$$\tau'=\wp(\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{p\}\cup U:U\in\mathscr{U}\big\}\;;$$

$\tau'$ is a topology on $X$, and $\tau'\supseteq\tau$, since $\mathscr{U}\supseteq\mathscr{F}$. However, $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is not first countable at $p$. If it were, there would be a sequence of distinct points of $\Bbb N$ converging to $p$. However, if $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any sequence of distinct points of $\Bbb N$, there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\{n_k:k\in\Bbb N\}\setminus U$ is infinite, and $\{p\}\cup U$ is then a nbhd of $p$ that does not contain a tail of the sequence.

Finally, let $\tau''=\wp(X)$, the discrete topology on $X$; clearly $\tau''\supseteq\tau'$, and $\langle X,\tau''\rangle$ is first countable.